# What's the difference between "javascript:;" and "javascript:" in href attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

What's the difference between "javascript:;" and "javascript:" in an anchor `href` attribute?

Comment: The first has a semicolon, the second does not have.

Comment: wondering about similarity? both are **bad**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same as the difference between empty Javascript file and Javascript file with just a `;`.

Nothing:

```
eval("");
//undefined
eval(";");
//undefined
```

See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9.1

> When, as the program is parsed from left to right, the end of the
>   input stream of tokens is encountered and the parser is unable to
>   parse the input token stream as a single complete ECMAScript Program,
>   then a semicolon is automatically inserted at the end of the input
>   stream.

So, empty file would be an invalid Program, then semicolon is inserted automatically, and it becomes equal to a Program with just a semicolon.

It just occurred to me that this is yet another case that prooves JSON is not a subset of Javascript: empty JSON is not valid:

```
JSON.parse("");
//SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
eval("");
//undefined
```

:P

Answer (score 6):

`javascript:` indicates the pseudo-protocol that can be used to evaluate JavaScript. So a single semicolon after it is equal to a script containing just `;` which is an empty expression that does nothing. `javascript:` without anything else after it is an empty script that also does nothing. In both cases the return values are `undefined` which is important since a `javascript:` url returning something else would result in the page contents being replaced with whatever it returned.

However, you should not use `javascript:` urls *at all* - they are deprecated. Use `onclick` and either a useful href or `#` if there is no non-js version of the link. Remember to preventDefault the event in that case though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I only want to correct you that page contents is not being replaced with what `javascript:` returns, try `javascript: 10` or `javascript: 'google.com'`, it won't do anything.

Comment: Also I won't agree that javascript: shouldn't be used, as it's always possible that someone will forget to `return false;` on onclick or function will throw an exception and you'll have a nasty and hard to figure out bug.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/MJ4nb/ - it *is* replaced with the expression's result... An exception being thrown won't be a problem if you `preventDefault()` early enough (I usually do it in the first line of the event handler if it should be done unconditionally)

Comment: where is it replaced? I don't see anything, click doesn't do anything at all, nothing happens.

Comment: Maybe not all browsers do it. In firefox I end up with `10` being shown instead of the previous content.

Comment: probably, in chrome nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

`javascript:` tells that there is a javascript statement coming rather than a link to another page. The `;` is the javascript statement. However, `;` won't execute anything, so this is a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

`javascript:;` is `javascript:` with and additional semicolon. Apart from that, there are no differences.